# semaphores in C

Tags: c, posix, semaphore

I'm working with semaphores in C , especifically to control the access to a shared memory zone in linux. but there is one thing that I can't understand.

I am using a mutex to control the access to a specific zone because i have 2 processes that must read/write from that zone. the thing is, when we use the fork() to create a new child process, the whole program is "copied" to another program as if they were two seperate programs right ? so, when i do V(mutex) in one process, how does the other one know he can't access  ?

I know its a noob question but nobody could explain this to me until now.

Comment: You could also sychronize by communication via good old IPC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You synchronisation objects must be placed in process shared memory, for example created with `mmap (... MAP_ANONYMOUS ...)`. In addition, they must have the `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` attribute set, for example, by using `pthread_mutexattr_setpshared`.

Comment: so you're saying that when i create my shmid i must atach the semaphore to it ?

Comment: If you're using System V shared memory and semaphores, you don't need to do anything special.

Comment: A nit but OP may not be using pthreads.  The analogous usage for PROCESS_SHARED for posix semaphores would be the 2nd parm (pshared) in `sem_init`.

Comment: i am but i dont really know what to do here. i need to have a variable (int) shared so i can acess the positions in memory in order. like process one accesses the 1st position and increments that variable so the process 2 knows that he must access the 2nd position. any tips ?

Comment: @Pedro Costa, you can do that with a pthread mutex as chill's answer suggests by setting the PROCESS_SHARED attribute on the mutex (and putting it into shared memory).  It won't be sufficient just to have your int ctr in shared mem, you also want to put whatever array you are operating in it too.  Furthermore while the mutex can protect access it won't guarantee what *order* the array is accessed.  You need some signaling mechanism (e.g. condition variable or similar) or some protocol *you* code (e.g. p1 only works on odd elements, p2 on even elements) to do that.

Comment: the signaloing mechanism i already have. i did this with just one process writing and another one reading. now with multiple processes writing and reading they all access position 0 and then all access position 1 and so on because the variable that tells the next position to access isnt shared in the memory. so i need a new memory space to store that value right ?

Comment: Yes but you need to put both the ctr variable and the array in shared memory if you want both processes actions available to the other.  If you just put the ctr there then the 2 programs are still working on their own copies of the array and neither will see the actions on the array made by the other party.

Comment: yeah but i've done that already and it works. the problem is i can't update the number of the positon in my new memory space. *(ptrOutDescarga) = *((ptrOutDescarga)+1), am i incrementing the value this way ?

Comment: ok this is the problem. im not incrementing the value in *(ptrOutDescarga) , thats why the processes always access to the position 0. is there any other way to increment the value in that segment of memory?

Comment: OK i just realised what the problem was... im such a dumb person. thank you all for your help !

Answer (score 2):

After the `fork` neither process is going to know about the memory actions of the other because they are separate copies.  You have to put your shared variables in shared memory, including mutexes and semaphores.  Then all the processes are operating on the same resource.

For unrelated (i.e. non-forked) process there are usually system facilities (e.g. named semaphores) that each process can open based on a path name or similar method that each can use to find and use the resource.

Answer (score 0):

See here:

[Semaphores and Mutex for Thread and Process Synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251701/semaphores-and-mutex-for-thread-and-process-synchronization)

So mutex in practice is often used in threads, which makes sharing trivial. For processes however, mutex could be stored as a part of the shared mem.

For semaphores however, linux has built in library, which identifies global semaphores by keys. See below.

http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/semaphores.html

Or you can use other IPC to sync. Signals, for example.

Hope this helps.

Comment: very nice, so the key i use for the semaphore would be the same i used for the shared memory space that i want to control ?

Comment: Actually no. The shared memory key should be irrelevant to the shared mem key, but different processes should use the same keys for semaphore. You could refer to the examples on the link above. So for your example, there could be one key for shared mem and one for semaphore. They don't need to be the same.